# Как выгрузить фотографию с сайта с помощью Python?

Tags: python

Мне трудно представить как это всё делается так как первый раз работаю с парсингом или чем-то подобным. В общем суть такова - даётся url картинки и мне надо загрузить её на сайт, а потом выгрузить с этого же сайта (и страницы) в обработанном виде. Уже несколько часов ищу материалы по этой теме, но понял что легче просто спросить. Сайт - Remove.bg

Comment: У сайта API имеется 50 картинок в месяц бестплатно https://www.remove.bg/api#get-started

Answer (score 1):

```
# Requires "requests" to be installed (see python-requests.org)
import requests

response = requests.post(
    'https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg',
    files={'image_file': open('Здесь пишешь путь к файлу который хочешь закачать на сайт например: C:\PyCharm\main\Penguins.jpg', 'rb')},
    data={'size': 'auto'},
    headers={'X-Api-Key': 'Здесь прописываешь API KEY свой'},
)
if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    with open('no-bg.png', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.content)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

Comment: Где взять этот Api key не могу понять

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Получение API KEY, кнопка находится сверху по ссылке которую ты оставил когда задавал вопрос